# Track/Log Dynamic method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, struct, metaprogramming

Need some help do some meta programming here. I am trying to find how many times each struct key is called in code. Is there a way i can do it without putting logging all across codebase?

Example:

```
class Test
 CONFIGS = ClosedStruct.new(name: "test", description: "Hello")
 def self.config
   CONFIGS
 end
end

Test.config.name
=> "test"
```

I want to know how many times .name and .description is called in code. Add logger for each call.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a separate log, you can log particular messages to file.

In order to log particular location of the call, you can use `caller_locations(1,1)[0]` which will log caller method, file location and line of code.

In order to prepend our log before each method call, you have to overwrite struct method via `prepend` in Struct, which will allow logs to occur before listed methods are being called.

It probably could be metaprogrammed even better in terms of prepending log automatically before each defined key, but I find this solution sufficient.

I'm curious if you could find a way to prepend log without defining list of methods, I think you'd have to overwrite the ClosedStruct#initialize class in order to prepend the module to have access to defined keys.

```rb
# test.rb

require 'closed_struct'
require_relative 'log_hooks'

class Test
 CONFIGS = ClosedStruct.new(name: "test", description: "Hello") do
    extend LogHooks

    log_before :name, :description
 end

 def self.config
   CONFIGS
 end
end
```

```rb
# log_hooks.rb

require 'logger'

module LogHooks
  def log_before(*method_names)
    to_prepend = Module.new do
      method_names.each do |name|
        define_method(name) do |*args, &block|
          logger = Logger.new('log.txt')
          logger.debug("Used #" + name.to_s + " in " + caller_locations(1,1)[0].to_s)
          super(*args,&block)
        end
      end
    end

    prepend to_prepend
  end
end
```

Example output in `log.txt`(created test.rb with code above used it in foo.rb and ran `ruby foo.rb`):

```
D, [2021-07-03T15:32:55.546654 #4491] DEBUG -- : Used #name in foo.rb:7:in `foo'
D, [2021-07-03T15:32:55.546833 #4491] DEBUG -- : Used #description in foo.rb:11:in `bar'
```

```rb
# foo.rb

require_relative 'test'

class Foo
  def self.foo
    Test.config.name
  end

  def bar
    Test.config.description
  end
end

Foo.foo
Foo.new.bar
```